# How do I turn off new mail notifications in Mountain Lion?

Tags: mail.app, macos, notifications

After upgrading to Mountain Lion, I'm receiving new email notifications.  I previously turned these off in the Mail application.  How do I turn them off now?

Answer (score 11):

In Mountain Lion, this is done in the Notifications under System Preferences.  Open System Preferences, select Notifications, choose Mail in the left pane, and then select "None".